# ImageView can't be clicked like a button

Tags: java, android, xml

- Everything is OK except the onClick() method.It didn't work at all.When I click the any of the 3 images,nothing happened.
- I know that I can solve the problem by using Button or ImageButton.But where is the bug in my code?
- Here is a part of my code:

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //......
      discover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.discover);
      to_new = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.to_new);
      me = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.me);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()){
      case R.id.discover:
          discover.setImageResource(R.drawable.discover_2);
          to_new.setImageResource(R.drawable.to_new);
          me.setImageResource(R.drawable.me);
          break;
      case R.id.to_new:
          discover.setImageResource(R.drawable.discover);
          to_new.setImageResource(R.drawable.to_new_2);
          me.setImageResource(R.drawable.me);
          break;
      case R.id.me:
          discover.setImageResource(R.drawable.discover);
          to_new.setImageResource(R.drawable.to_new);
          me.setImageResource(R.drawable.me_2);
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blank"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/discover"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/discover"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/to_new"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/to_new"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/me"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/me"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make check box instead of imageview

Answer (score 5):

you didn't call `setOnClickLister` on your views. E.g.

```
me.setOnClickListener(this);
```

`this`, in this case is your Activity which is implementing the `View.OnClickListener` interface. This way you are telling the view, that when the click event occurs, the `onClick` method implemented in `this` object has to be invoked

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set OnClickListener in your onCreate().

For more detail example below is the reference link.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

```
discover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    to_new.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    me.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

call onclick method inside on create method

discover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

to_new.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
me.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: call  your onClick() method inside oncreate method u forgetted that